# What is the difference between abolish/1 and retractall/1?

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

From reading the manual, I can't seem to find the difference between the two.

The manual says:

> It is advised to use retractall/1 for erasing all clauses of a dynamic predicate.

So I chose to use `retractall/1` in my program; however, I wonder what the difference is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `retractall/1` standard built-in predicate can be used to remove all clauses for a dynamic predicate but the predicate will still be known by the runtime. The `abolish/1` standard built-in predicate, in the other hand, not only removes all predicate clauses but also makes the predicate unknown to the runtime. If you try to call a dynamic predicate after removing all its clauses using `retractall/1`, the call simply fails. But if you abolish a dynamic predicate, calling it after will result in a predicate existence error.

Answer (score 8):

In analogy to SQL:

`retractall(table_name(_,_,_))` could be `delete from table_name`, while
`abolish(table_name/3)` would play as `drop table_name`

Comment: Excellent analogy, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Before I read your question and [@PauloMoura's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486080/4609915), I didn't know the answer either.

With this answer I don't want to copy Paulo's answer. Instead, I suggest you consider reading/searching alternative Prolog-related sources:

- [The ISO directives, control constructs and builtins](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html#retract)—[iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog) on SO
- [4.12.5 Removing Clauses from the Database](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dmdb_002drcd.html)—[sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) [manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/)
- [**8.7**  Dynamic clause management](http://gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec101)—[gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog) [manual](http://gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html)
- [**Chapter 9** Dynamic Clauses and Global Variables](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/download/manual.pdf)—[bprolog](/questions/tagged/bprolog) [manual](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/download/manual.pdf)
- [**6.14** Asserting, Retracting, and Other Database Modifications](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/manual1/manual1.pdf)—[xsb](/questions/tagged/xsb) [manual](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/manual2/index.html)
- [**6.10.1** Modification of the Data Base](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/yap.html#Modifying-the-Database)—part of the [yap](/questions/tagged/yap) [manual](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/yap.html)

Note that the above [*may or may not*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) directly fit [the Prolog system you use](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db).

Still, having multiple sources is a good thing: It can keep you from getting stuck!